# how to solve this code(ACTIVITY doesn't load and stop the app)?

Tags: java, android

I tried to fix this code but I didn't succeed

I don't know what shutted this app

```
    Activity a=new Activity();

public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putString("message", "This is my message to be reloaded");
    PersistableBundle bb=new PersistableBundle();
    bb.putString("m1","m2");
   a.onSaveInstanceState(outState,bb);
}


public void onCreate() {
    Activity a=new Activity();
    Bundle b=new Bundle();
    PersistableBundle bb=new PersistableBundle();
    bb.putString("m1","m2");

    a.onCreate(b,bb);
    int x=R.layout.activity_client;
    a.setContentView(x);
```

Comment: Why are you doing `new Activity()`?

Comment: because I need methods in class `Activity`

Comment: But you're already _in_ an `Activity` by the looks of things (though you haven't made that clear). If this inside some other type of class (e.g. a `Fragment`), then you need to find some way of communicating with the owning `Activity`. You should not be creating new `Activity` instances with `new Activity()` - they are created when you (or someone else) calls `startActivity`.

Comment: i try this  why still isn't working and stopped the aspp

Comment: We can't possibly know what you did wrong with a vague description like _"i try this"_. You need to be very specific and explain exactly what you did (preferably by showing the code, and the resulting stacktrace / error message).